# I have a json file and when I click the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a json file and when I click the button, it displays only last json data(*Ipsum %40*). But I want to parse that way; it must display *"Lorem"* in `#choice1` `div` and *"Ipsum"* in `#choice2` `div`. How can I do that? Here are my codes below;

**JS:**

```
$("#getdata-button").click(function() {
  $.getJSON('json_data.txt', function(read_data) {
    $.each(read_data.result, function(i, data) {
      $("#choice1").html(data.option + data.percent);
      $("#choice2").html(data.option + data.percent);
    });
  });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<button id="getdata-button">hello</button>
<div id="choice1"></div><br>
<div id="choice2"></div>
```

**JSON:**

```
{
  "result": [{
    "option": "Lorem",
    "percent": " %50"
  }, {
    "option": "Ipsum",
    "percent": " %32"
  }]
}
```

Comment: You should try to properly indent the code so that it is easier to read. And did you read the description of the [tag:data] tag? (`DO NOT USE THIS TAG! This tag is hopelessly broad and doesn't really tell us what the question is about`)

Comment: You should not do `each` in your case, because second iteration will replace results of first iteration. Use array indexer (`data[0].option` etc) instead.

Comment: *"It displays `%40`! Here's my JSON: ...%50 %32"* :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, instead of saving your file as `json_data.txt`, save it as `json_data.json`.  Update your `$.getJSON` URL to match it.

Secondly, in this case you probably don't need to use an `$.each`.  This will solve your problem:

```
$("#getdata-button").click(function() {
  $.getJSON('json_data.txt', function(read_data) {
      $('#choise1').html(read_data.result[0].option + read_data[0].percent);
      $('#choise2').html(read_data.result[1].option + read_data[1].percent);
  });
});
```

If you actually do need to use an `$.each`, then this is how you would do it:

```
$("#getdata-button").click(function() {
  $.getJSON('json_data.txt', function(read_data) {
      $.each(read_data.result, function(i, data) {
          $('#choise' + (i + 1)).html(data.option + data.percent)
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: Regarding your second code snippet: It's better to generate all HTML for the choices in memory and after the loop add it to the DOM. Otherwise you'll trigger a reflow on every iteration which is highly unperformant.

Comment: Fair enough.  Normally I would create a new element outside of the DOM, make whatever changes I need, and then replace the targeted element that is inside of the DOM.  Just trying to demonstrate the concept to OP rather than get into the specifics of jQuery performance :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#getdata-button").click(function() {
    $.getJSON('json_data.txt', function(read_data) {
        $("#choise1").html(read_data.result[0].option + read_data.result[0].percent);
        $("#choise2").html(read_data.result[1].option + read_data.result[1].percent);
    });
});
```

Probably the easiest solution for you.
If you have more than just 2 entries you might want to iterate over it with "for" like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < read_data.result.length; i++) {
    //Access the json like this:
    //read_data_result[i]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For every Item in the Object, you set choise1 and choise2 to that value. So the second time it calls that $.each Function, it overrides the choise1 and choise2 with that Value.
You should do the following:

```
$("#getdata-button").click(function() {
  $.getJSON('json_data.txt', function(read_data) {
    $("choise1").val(read_data[0].option + read_data[0].percent);
    $("choise2").val(read_data[1].option + read_data[1].percent);
  });
});
```

That should now work. If not, please tell me. Feel free to use this code in any Form for any Purpose.

Greetings,

Max

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it didn't work. When I click the button, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution would be doing something like this:

```
<button id="getdata-button">hello</button>
<div id="choices"></div>

<script>
$("#getdata-button").click(function() {
  $.getJSON('data.txt', function(read_data) {
    var choices = '';
    $.each(read_data.result, function(i, data) {
      choices += '<div id="choise">' + data.option + data.percent + '</div><br>';
    });
    $("#choices").html( choices );
  });
});
</script>
```

so first generate the HTML for all the choices in memory and then add it to the DOM. Don't add things to your DOM in a loop, it will trigger are reflow on every iteration which is slow.